# Comma separated values in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a column:

```
Name
John,Doe
```

I want the output from select as

```
First name Last name
John       Doe
```

How to remove comma separated data in mysql?

Answer (score 1):

I would say that this breaks first normal form.  Don't store two data items in a single column.  If you want two items, use two columns.

If you must, please refer to [this documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html).  As you can see, MySQL doesn't have a string split function.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below query to do that,

```
select SUBSTRING_INDEX('John,Doe', ',', 1) as str1, SUBSTRING_INDEX('John,Doe', ',', -1) as str2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
'FirstName, MiddleName, LastName',
SUBSTRING_INDEX('FirstName, MiddleName, LastName', ',', 1) 
    AS `First Name`,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX('FirstName, MiddleName, LastName', ',', 2), ',', -1) 
    AS  `Middle Name`,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX('FirstName, MiddleName, LastName', ',', 3), ',', -1) 
    AS  `Last Name`
```

See output of this query [here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/056ce/2)